# Instance method not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am taking a warning from Xcode :

```
Instance method '-presentModalViewController:animated:completion:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Here is the code:

```
    NewsWebViewController *sampleView = [[[NewsWebViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I try your different solution before to you contact,
Please considerate my apology, i'm french and i translate with google translate.

In you thanking by advance.

Comment: what type of object is self ?

Comment: There is no such method, it's presentViewController:animated:completion:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is called [`presentViewController:animated:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a).

There is no `Modal` in this selector.

Comment: Good +1, I still have more than two warning to correct, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the reference documentation for `UIViewController`. The name of the method is:

```
presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

There is a deprecated method named:

```
presentModalViewController:animated:
```

Comment: Good +1, I still have more than two warning to correct, thank you :)